# Is my hiragana writing understandable?

Tags: hiragana, handwriting

I've started to begin writing hiragana but I've seen many ways of writing them, usually I'm able to read the different ways of writing them but it keeps bothering me sometimes how mine and what I see don't look similar and would like to know if my writing is understandable. Thank you in advance
[image]

Comment: You should try writing in boxes for now.  It'll help you pay attention to the proportions, which will help you make nicer looking characters.  You can buy or [print](http://print-kids.net/print/kokugo/hiragana-rensyuu/) special paper for practicing writing, or you can buy a notebook of graph paper.  (You can write in 2x2 boxes at a time so you can see where the center of each box is as you write.)  Also see [the video Choko linked below](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvUoakQf3I8).

Answer (score 8):

I think the only character one would stumble over is い, because it looks close like a し with either a bit of dirt, or like an incomplete じ. The rest of characters are definitely legible.

Two comments:

- き and さ are written with a gap in the curve (in handwriting).
- The next character I would point out would be に, which looks too much like two characters しこ.

Otherwise, good job and keep practising!

Comment: でも、本当にOPの「う」が読みやすいと思いますか。

Comment: @virmaior Legible doesn't mean easy to read. The handwriting reminds me of first year boys' handwriting. I think any native Japanese would have no problem reading all characters except い (including う). To achieve balance in the characters OP definitely has to put in a lot more practice, but that's just natural as s/he's just starting...

Comment: okay, got it...

Comment: I tend to agree with virmaior. The う　looks like a つ to me with an incomplete voiced consonant mark. But I'm not a native speaker, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old but your "ki" and your "sa" are wrong.

Edit: In handwriting, the curve in き and さ are usually and commonly not connected and instead separated into two strokes; but in some sans-serif fonts in Japanese, those strokes are connected. You're not completely wrong, but it's more customary to separate them into two strokes.

Comment: No, they are not wrong.　http://blog-imgs-55.fc2.com/a/b/e/abehavior/2012110823125017c.jpg